# Data Storage and Retrieval in Relational Database

Tags: c++, mysql, database-design, relational-database

I'm starting a project- Mini Database System, basically a small database like MySQL. I'm planning to use C++, I read several articles and understood that tables will be stored and retrieved using files. Further I need to use B+ trees for accessing and updating of data.

Can someone explain me with example how data will be actually stored inside files, 
For example I've a database "test" with table "student" in it.

student(id,name,grade,class) with some of the student entries. So how the entries of this table will be stored inside the file, whether it will stored in single file, or divided into files if later, then how ?

Comment: I will be held however you define it to be held. The B+ tree is a means to speed up lookup (since it's several levels in memory rather than on disk).

Comment: @StoryTeller I just want to know how do store data inside the files for a particular table.

Comment: Didn't the resources you read cover that? You store B+ tree nodes (only the "pointers" become file positions), and the data is stored in whichever format you wish. Specifics about optimizing file structure for HDD performance are things people wrote PhD theses over.

Comment: @StoryTeller I was just expecting a example(student table), it would be very helpful.

Comment: Totally agree with @StoryTeller here. There are simple ready-to-use solutions, which you will not even get close to with your own coding.

Answer (score 0):

A B+Tree on disk is a bunch of fixed-length blocks.  Your program will read/write whole blocks.

Within a block, there are a variable number of records.  Those are arranged by some mechanism of your choosing, and need to be ordered in some way.

"Leaf nodes" contain the actual data.  In "non-leaf nodes", the "records" contain pointers to child nodes; this is the way BTrees work.

B+Trees have the additional links (and maintenance hassle) of chaining blocks at the same level.

Wikipedia has some good discussions.

Comment: I want to know how data is stored in files, as I asked for student table, In what way I store data of this table inside file(s). I read many articles but were not up to the point, can you just elaborate with a help of a example.

Comment: The "blocks" (16KB in the case of MySQL's InnoDB) are stored in a file.  In C++, you use open, seek, write, close.  (Or maybe it is fopen, fseek, fwrite, fclose?  I haven't touched C++ in a decade.)

Comment: I'm not asking for code
for e.g. this is the table
1|Rick|A|NY

2|James|C|CA

3|john|D|India
so, should I add all this data inside in one file or divide this data according to primary key and other meta data in several files, if later than how, please explain the example taken.

Comment: Now you are getting into the question of how to implement indexes (aka keys).

Comment: A BTree has an ordering (else it would not be a BTree).  With MySQL's InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` provides the ordering for the data's B+Tree.  Secondary keys are in their own B+Trees.

Comment: Whether you (1) put all the "blocks" into a single file or (2) have one file per BTree or (3) have one file for the data+PK and one file for all the secondary keys -- that is your choice.  InnoDB uses either (1) or (3) depending on a global setting.  MyISAM does not order the data, and has all keys (including PK) as (3).